# SQLite Context.MODE_PRIVATE

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to know:

Can we use `Context.MODE_PRIVATE` in `SQLite` while Database creating to protect from unwanted Database access.

I am not getting any example on google.
How to use this `Context.MODE_PRIVATE` in  Database.
Please assist me. Provide any link or sample.

[IN THIS LINK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_PRIVATE) they are talking about file. so Database is also file.

How can i implement this?

Comment: any link can u provide please .which uses this line on database creation.

Comment: SQLite databases on internal storage are private by default. Files on internal storage can only be accessed by your app. The exception is on devices that have been rooted, in which case the user can access your internal storage.

Comment: Thanks commonsWare you always give perfect ans..but i want to ask ,what i am trying is it possible.

Comment: or i can say in external sdcard there is no private ..all are public right?

Comment: Yes, every application that have permission to external storage access may get access to your application files stored external. But when you store your DB internal the only way to access it by another application is to use console commands with root rights, so this may take place only on rooted phones.

Comment: @Androiduser: I suppose doubt the code you shared, can you provide more link which uses so. If am not wrong, flag used used will be [OPEN_READONLY](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#OPEN_READONLY) or [OPEN_READWRITE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#OPEN_READWRITE) and not the context.MODE_PRIVATE

Answer (score 0):

As commonsware mentioned, SQLite databases on internal storage are private by default. But as mentioned by others rooted phone as always access to your file.

Rather you can use any encryption algorithm to save the data in DB which will help you to restrict the readability unless intruder know the encryption algorithm.

You cant set "Context.MODE_PRIVATE" flag in SQLite.

Answer (score 0):

While creating database, following syntax is useful

```
openOrCreateDatabase(String path, int mode, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory)
```

For example,

```
openOrCreateDatabase("StudentDB",Context.MODE_PRIVATE,null);
```

See my tutorial on [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/88b6e5/sqlitedatabase-connectivity/) site.

Comment: it says "Required Type CursorFactory on the MODE_PRIVATE

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1**: Use [SQLcipher](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/).

**Option 2**: Secure Method Ever No Chance To Hack. It is not perfect, but it is better than nothing.

> 1) Insert data using this Function:

```
public static String getEncryptedString(String message) {
    String cipherText = null;

    try {
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(("YOUR-SECURE-PASSWORD-KEY").getBytes(), "AES"));
        byte[] bytes = cipher.doFinal(message.getBytes());
        cipherText = Base64.encodeToString(bytes, Base64.DEFAULT);
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        cipherText = "Error in encryption";
        Log.e(TAG , ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return cipherText;
}
```

> 2) Get data from the database and pass into this function parameter:

```
//This function returns output string 
public static String getDecryptedString(String encoded) {
    String decryptString = null;

    try {
        byte[] bytes = Base64.decode(encoded, Base64.DEFAULT);

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(("YOUR-SECURE-PASSWORD-KEY").getBytes() , "AES"));
        decryptString = new String(cipher.doFinal(bytes), "UTF-8");
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        decryptString = "Error in decryption";
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return decryptString;
}
```

> 3) Benefits of these methods:
>   - Not possible to decrypt without the right Key.
>   - AES Encryption is a very secure encryption method.
>
> 4) Store your AES key in the c++ file.