# Why i can not open sqlite database in android service?

Tags: android

I beginner in android and want to open sqlite database in android service:
write this code:

```
public class MyService extends Service {

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        try {

                SQLiteDatabase db;
                db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_NAME, this.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    }catch(Exception e){
    }

        return Service.START_FLAG_REDELIVERY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

but in this line :

```
db = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_NAME, this.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
```

i get this error:
[image]

what happen?how can i solve that?thanks.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14848402/sqlite-context-mode-private](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14848402/sqlite-context-mode-private)

Comment: `SQLiteDatabase#openOrCreateDatabase` takes `String` / `File` path and `CursorFactory`  factory, you most likely mix it up with `Context#openOrCreateDatabase`

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, `MODE_PRIVATE` is static, and you are trying to access it using an instance of `Context` (`this` in your case, as `Service` is a subclass of `Context`).

You can see that MODE_PRIVATE is static in [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_PRIVATE):

> ```
> public static final int MODE_PRIVATE
> ```

Change your code like this:

```
db = this.openOrCreateDatabase(DATABASE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
```

I suggest you to take a look at [Understanding Class Members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) from The Java™ Tutorials

Also, take into account the comments by @pskink and read [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/content/Context.html#openOrCreateDatabase(java.lang.String,%20int,%20android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory)) of the `openOrCreateDatabase` method in the `Context` class.

Comment: `SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase` does not have any `int` parameter, read the documentation

Comment: @pskink you are right, I tried to point out how to solve the error shown in the capture and I didn't review the rest of the line. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: @user3671271 of course you can read a sqlite database from a `Service`, as `Service` extends `Context`